# Solr More Like This Request Handler doesn't return score

Tags: solr

I am using Solr to search for "more like this" content. The field which mlt should operate on has normally the length of a sentence. So I am actually searching for mlt sentences.

I have configured a mlt request handler in the solrconfig.xml

```xml
<requestHandler name="/mlt" class="solr.MoreLikeThisHandler">
    <str name="mlt.fl">content</str>
    <str name="mlt.mintf">0</str>
    <str name="mlt.mindf">0</str>
  </requestHandler>
```

The corresponding schema.xml

```xml
<schema name="MyAppSchema" version="1.6">

    <field name="content" type="text_mlt" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" />

    <fieldType name="text_mlt" class="solr.TextField" termVectors="true" >
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" />
            <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

</schema>
```

When I am now execute requests against this mlt RequestHandler I get results but without the matching score. Is it possible to return the score too when using the Request Handler?

One example in the documentation displays the score of mlt but only when using the [SearchHandler](https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_8/morelikethis.html#search-component-query-and-response).

Comment: Does including `score` in `mlt.fl` help?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I think mlt.fl should hold the fields More Like This operates on and is not related to score.